Combine animations
I have a simple animation with two moving parts. How can I speed up and slow down the two parts together?
I want the counters to start slowly, speed up, and slow down at the end.


you can do this in the VSE.

select your strip
add-> effect strip -> speed control



change speed control to multiply and keyframe the multiply factor


result:
https://imgur.com/a/5vRecsN

This looks great! Thank you. I now need to go and learn about the Video Sequencer...

yes you should! it's pretty powerful ;)

You can do it in the NLA:
Push down each action into the NLA:

Once done, select the strip, open the N panel, activate the Animated Strip Time option, go to frame 1 of the Timeline and keyframe the Strip Time value at 1 for example, then at frame 100 of the Timeline keyframe the Strip Time value at 50 for example, which means that from the frame 1 to 100 of the Timeline it will play the frame 1 to 50 of the action, so it will begin slower than the normal speed. Go on with the Strip Time values you want in order to speed up or slow donw as much as you want. Do the exact same thing for the other strip so that the 2 strips are synchronized:


This is what I was hoping to achieve, but I find the NLA confusing and unintuitive for the most part.

What exactly don't you understand in the NLA?
